# Installing everything from legit source anonymously

Tags: configuration

I would like you to anwser this question with a fastforwarded quickguide to full instalation including your suggestion for your preffered security methods to stay anonmymous and avoid viruses. There is alot of tricksters out there and i want the info from the legit source.

Answer (score 1):

what you want to install "everything"? man, you didn't give us any information.

go to the library or university, don't use your home computer, download whonix or cubeos, install it on your laptop/pc and learn how to use it. they have forums for their OS. of course, you can first install tor to download whonix but it will be very slow and very long. it is simplier to visit library or university if you don't need to login to download something.